# Fetch set or rows from table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table `Exam_record` with the data. I need to know how to pullout the latest 2 record for each EID based on `latest exam date.`

```
EID | Exam_name | score | date_of_completion |
-----------------------------------------------
1   | Exam_1    | 60    | 23-Jun-2014        |
1   | Exam_1    | 70    | 10-Jan-2014        |
1   | Exam_1    | 71    | 15-Aug-2014        |
1   | Exam_1    | 65    | 1-Sep-2014         |
2   | Exam_2    | 50    | 2-Jul-2014         |
2   | Exam_2    | 55    | 12-May-2014        |
2   | Exam_2    | 65    | 15-Apr-2014        |
```

Desired output is

```
EID | Exam_name | score | date_of_completion |
-----------------------------------------------
1   | Exam_1    | 71    | 15-Aug-2014        |
1   | Exam_1    | 65    | 1-Sep-2014         |
2   | Exam_2    | 55    | 12-May-2014        |
2   | Exam_2    | 50    | 2-Jul-2014         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by EID order by  date_of_completion desc) as rn from table
)x
where x<=2
```

[more info](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)